# Parallel lines assumption for ordinal regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit

I used the lrm function of the RMS package for a ordinal regression model for prediction. When I use the graphical plot method, the parallel line assumption seems to fail for some variables. Is there any way the parallel lines assumption can be relaxed ? ? Does the lrm package get around the assumption ?

Another question would be is whether Hosmer–Lemeshow test would be valuable in interpreting this despite the invalid assumption ? Is there an implementation in R for HS gof test for ordinal regression ?

Your response will be much appreciated.

Comment: I just answered the personal email you sent on this topic.  Please do not ask the same question in two different places.  My answer was:  I've seen worse fits, but it's a tough call.  You always have to ask if another approach would make things better or worse (because of higher variance from more parameters if sample size is not huge, or because of worse fit in other ways).

To relax that assumption you need the R `vgam` package.

I don't use Hosmer-Lemeshow.  There is a better test from Hosmer and le Cessie - see the help file for `residuals.lrm` in `rms`.